# Can you do dictionaries in qml?

Tags: application-development, programming, ubuntu-sdk, qml, syntax

So for example:

```
Item {
    id: sylvainLikesAnsweringMyQuestions
    property var myDict: {[key,value],[anotherKey,anotherValue]}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In JavaScript/QML, objects are data (variables), with properties and methods.
You can also create your own objects.

This example creates an object called "results", and adds four properties to it:

```
property var results: {"passed": 15, "failed": 2, "skipped": 1, "IlikeYourQuestions": 1};
```

You could also add methods to it, but with just a set of properties, it works exactly like a dictionary.

You can access the object properties in two ways:

```
results.passed;
results["passed"];
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp